# Как указать версию composer-пакета при публикации?

Tags: php, composer, packagist

Доброго дня, сделал небольшой пакет для composer и пытаюсь подключить его для проверки в другой проект. но composer require не скачивает пакет ссылаясь на то, что нет стабильной версии пакета.
" Could not find package xtfkpi/image-loader at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability "

На самом сервисе packagist для пакета показывается только версия dev-master, хотя в других пакетах на сайте можно найти разные версии пакета. Подскажите, как все же указать версию пакета, чтобы его потом можно было нормально инсталлировать? 
 composer.json сейчас выглядит так:

```js
{
    "name": "xtfkpi/img-loader",
    "description": "package for image download",
    "stability":"stable",
    "version":"1.0.1",
    "type": "package",
    "minimum-stability":"dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.0"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "xtfkpi",
            "email": "xtfkpi@yopmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "xtfkpi\\Imgloader\\": "src"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Версия либо указывается явно в composer.json, либо берется из тега системы контроля версий; здесь по явным причинам нет ни того, ни того. Как подсказали в удаленном ответе, вы можете снизить требования к стабильности подтягиваемых пакетов и получить таким образом dev-master.

Comment: Не могу найти пакет на packagist, так задумано? Upd: нашёл)

Comment: Это тестовое задание на работу? Думаю стоит вынести исключения в свои файлы

Comment: Также `psr-2` не позволяет управляющие структуры(if/while) без фигурных скобок)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"minimum-stability":"dev"`

Ваша библиотека не имеет стабильных(stable) версий, поэтому не может быть подключена в `stable` проект.
Нужно либо зарелизить `stable` версию без dev-зависимостей, либо понизить требования проекта до `dev`

---

Лучше всего вообще удалить `version` из `composer.json`

Для версионирования же просто использовать имена веток и теги в репозитории
Они неплохо поддерживаются `packagist`

```
git tag v0.0.1
```